# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a blog post and have received the Template::Error. I have searched and I know it is an easy fix but can not figure this out. I don't know what I am missing so any help is greatly appreciated.

**articles_controller**

> ```
>  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
>  def new
> @article = Article.new   end 
>  def create 
> @article = Article.new(article_params)
> if  @article.save
>   flash[:success] = "Article was successfully created"
>   redirect_to article_path(@article)
> else
>   render 'new'
> end    end 
>  def show       end 
>  def edit       end 
>  def update
> if @article.update(article_params)
>   flash[:success] = "Article was updated"
>   redirect_to article_path(!article)
> else
>   flash[:success] = "Article was not updated"
>   render 'edit'
> end    end 
>  def index
> @articles = Article.all   end 
>  def destroy    @article.destroy    flash[:success] = "Article was deleted"    redirect_to articles_path   end 
>
>   private
> def article_params
>   params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
> end 
>
> def set_article
>   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
> end    end
> ```

**show.html.erb**

```
<h2 align="center">Title: <%= @article.title %></h2>
<div class="well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
 <h4 class="center"><strong>Description:</strong></h4>
 <hr>
 <%= @article.description %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `@article` in your `show` action:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

Or use a `before_action` callback:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: :show

  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought with the set_article being that exact code, I would not need to write this out again. Is it because it is set as private, the show.html.erb file cannot access the set_article?

Comment: You need somehow to invoke that method to set that instance variable. A before_action callback is the most common way.